# Opening all sheets of a spreadsheet by single call of xlsread in MATLAB

Tags: excel, matlab, xlsread

We can extract specific sheet using this function in MATLAB:

```
out = xlsread(filename,sheet);
```

How we can extract more than one sheet using single call of this function? I don't want use a loop and read the the file again and again for extracting different sheets data.

Comment: Use [actxserver](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/actxserver.html) instead.

Answer (score 1):

`xlsread` does not support reading multiple sheets at once. You have to use a loop.

As an alternative you could create your own `xlsread` function which has more capabilities. The relevant code is placed in `toolbox\matlab\iofun\xlsread.m` and `toolbox\matlab\iofun\private\xls*.m` You could create a copy of these functions and modify them to support multiple sheets.